# How to create an array of sets in Raphael?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, raphael

The below code will draw 48 squares with the numbers 0 to 47 inside them
I have read on stackoverflow that using sets is the best way to do this, as Im grouping the rectangle shape with its text number together so I can just reference them both with `location`
I have lots of locations so I want to put them in the array called `locations`.
The `locations[]` array is therefore a list of rectangles (which themselves are sets) that have a number in them.

```
window.onload = function() {  
var paper = new Raphael(document.getElementById('canvas_container'), 1200, 1000);  
var locations = []; 
var location = paper.set();

//squares have same width and height.
var width = 12;

// draw 48 locations
for (i=0; i<48;i++) {
    location.push(paper.rect(width*(i+1),10, width, width));
    location.push(paper.text(width*(i+1)+(width/2),width+(width/3),i).attr({ "font-size": 8, "font-family": "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" }));

    locations[i] = location;
    location.length = 0; //clears the set
}

//locations[9].translate(Math.random() * 350, Math.random() * 380);

}
```

The problem is the last line. If I uncomment it out, all of the 48 boxes will be translated and move together.
All I want to do is move the 10th square.
Im obviously doing something wrong with my arrays and how I populate them but I have no idea.

Comment: last line in `for` loop doesn't help much. You have built `locations` array where each item contains 2*48 elements (rect and text). You can see that with `console.log(locations[0]);` Because of that `transform` moves everything around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Last line in for loop did not cleared set. You have built locations array where each item contains 2*48 elements (rect and text). You can see that with `console.log(locations[0]);` Because of that transform moves everything around.

Rearanged so that each array item contains just one pair (rect, text):

```
window.onload = function() {  

var paper = new Raphael('canvas_container', 1200, 1000);  
var locations = []; 
var location = paper.set();

function Item(elem, text) {
    this.elem = elem;
    this.text = text;
}

//squares have same width and height.
var width = 12;

var item;

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

    item = new Item(
            paper.rect(width * (i+1), 10, width, width),
            paper.text(width * (i+1) + (width/2), width + (width/3), i).attr({ "font-size": 8, "font-family": "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" })
        );

    locations[i] = item;
}

location = paper.set();
location.push(locations[3].elem);
location.push(locations[3].text);

location.translate(Math.random() * 350, Math.random() * 380);

}
```

[Demo at fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gTTH4/) and [update](http://jsfiddle.net/gTTH4/1/) with random selection.